# Show that this difficult sequence converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$x_1=\sqrt{2},\,x_2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}},\, x_3=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}},\, \cdots$

How to show that the sequence converges? We can say that it is monotonic but if it is bounded?

Answer (score 2):

You have that: $x_n = \sqrt{2+x_{n-1}}$. You can show by induction that this is an increasing sequence and is bounded above by $2$. So it converges to $L$. Then: $L = \sqrt{2+L}$, and solve this to get: $L = 2$

Comment: The $L$ is not quite right.